# Strange interaction between unicodemath and siunitx

Tags: math-mode, luatex, siunitx, unicode-math

I have a document, where for different reasons, I use `unicode-math` and `siunitx`. When I load `unicode-math` some units whose symbols are usually slanted (as math variables) are not slanted anymore.

Why is that? Do you know a workaround?

Here it is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% this makes e appear straight (not math)

\begin{document}
\noindent

\SI{1.234}{\planckbar^{-4}\elementarycharge^{2}} %the outcome depends on loading unicode-math

$1.234 \hbar^{-4} e^2$ %this is always ok

\end{document}
```

Output (note the `e` symbol, electron charge, it should appear slanted)

[image: unicodeplussiunitx]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326123/73) provides a perfectly good solution, but it might be useful to understand why this is happening.

Internally, `siunitx` resolves input into constructs of the form

```
$\mathrm{<unit-output>}$
```

so here

```
$\mathrm{\text{\ensuremath{e}}}$
```

With classical TeX, switching math-text-math gets us 'back to normal' in font terms so we can the normal italic font for letters without any explicit formatting. However, with `unicode-math` this doesn't seem to happen: nested font changes stay active. As as result, the usual set up gives incorrect results.

I'll see whether this can be addressed at the `unicode-math` end or whether a change in `siunitx` is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Something weird is happening when `\text` is processed in the argument of `\SI`. Here's a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% this makes e appear straight (not math)
\usepackage{siunitx,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathnormalsymbol}{m}{\text{$\mathnormal{#1}$}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\elementarycharge}{\mathnormalsymbol{e}}

\begin{document}

\SI{1.234}{\planckbar^{-4}\elementarycharge^{2}}

$1.234\, \hbar^{-4} e^2$ %this is always ok

\end{document}
```

[image]